# Azure App Insights -- How to get the user ID or email for an AAD authenticated visitor?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Static Web App and App Insights running using the standard set of telemetry code found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#snippet-setup-ignore-if-using-npm-setup

I am wondering how I can get the user details using my AAD-protected website? My website generates authentication information that an individual can access by tacking on `/.auth/me` to the end of the website URL, which looks like, and I am wondering if this is possibly a way to do it.

```
{
  "clientPrincipal": {
    "identityProvider": "aad",
    "userId": "xxxx",
    "userDetails": "xxxx",
    "userRoles": [
      "authenticated",
      "anonymous"
    ]
  }
}
```

In related posts, this thread seems fairly related to my interests but I cannot make much of anything from the discussion: [Azure - App Insights - how to track the logged-in Username in Auth Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988481/azure-app-insights-how-to-track-the-logged-in-username-in-auth-id)

Comment: User Id will be available under Application insight - >(Usage) Users - >Click on View More insights- > View user time line -> There you will find user id. However, could you please be more specific with your ask? Are you trying to fetch these details in your static website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want user id details using your AAD-protected website .
Here are the steps to know the `user ID` and details:

Go to Application insight >  View Application Insights data.
[image]

Go to users > Click on View more insights

[image]

After scroll down to select as below
[image]

As Selected Authentication user ID  > Click on  User Timeline  to check the details of **USER**.
[image]

For more information Please refer this similar [So thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793926/how-is-application-insight-tracking-the-user-id)